# Why didn't my one liner block work?

Tags: ruby, hash, block

I saw this on codequizzes.com:

> Convert this
>
> ```
> people = [["bob", 320], ["edgar", 152], ["maria", 125]]
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> {"bob" => 320, "edgar" => 152, "maria" => 125}
> ```
>
> Answer:
>
> ```
> Hash[people]
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> people.inject({}) do |memo, (name, number)|
>   memo[name] = number
>   memo
> end
> ```

The above all worked.  However, my one-liner answer below didn't:

```
people.inject({}) {|memo, (name, number)| memo[name] = number }
```

I got this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for 320:Fixnum
```

What's wrong with my one-liner?

Comment: Why do you think there is a line with only `memo` in the sample answer? Do you think the author wrote that without meaning?

Comment: @sawa, the OP has been editing the question. I don't think it was there initially, but it doesn't matter. Edit: I see I just missed that.

Comment: `people.to_h`, available in Ruby 2.1 +.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to return `memo` :

```
people.inject({}) {|memo, (name, number)| memo[name] = number; memo }
```

`Hash#[]=`  returns the *value* after assigning. And in your *block*, you are adding *value* to the *key* using the method `#[]=`, and the *value* is being returned and assigned to the `memo`. Your `memo` is a `Fixnum` instance, and on which in the very *next* iteration, `#[]=` has been called, like `320#[]=`. But `Fixnum#[]=` doesn't exist, so you got the expected error.

But using `#each_with_object`, you don't need to return `memo` :

```
people.each_with_object({}) {|(name, number), memo| memo[name] = number }
```

The above will work.

Comment: Awesome explanation to this newbie!  Thanks a lot! each_with_object didn't work though...got TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer
        from (irb):236:in `[]='

Comment: @dreamfly fixed it now,.

Comment: @Arup...yes I just found out too...just more more little thing to remember--swap the sequence of the parms.